# Definition for union of spans

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $K, L$ two sub-sets of $V$, a vector space.
Consider:
$$Sp(K)\cup Sp(L)$$

What is the right definition for the union of those spans?

Is it:
$$\{v\in V : v=\alpha\cdot k + \beta\cdot l  \}$$

where $\alpha, \beta \in F$ and $k\in K, l \in L$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The union is just that - the union, defined in the usual, set-theoretic way. That is:
$$Sp(K) \cup Sp(L) = \{v \in V : v \in Sp(K) \text{ or } v \in Sp(L)\}$$
Note that this is generally not a subspace of $V$. For instance, if $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, then we might have $Sp(K) = \text{ the x-axis}$ and $Sp(L) = \text{ the y-axis}$. Then $(1, 0), (0, 1) \in Sp(K) \cup Sp(L)$ but $(1, 0) + (0, 1) = (1, 1) \notin Sp(K) \cup Sp(L)$.

This last point answers your second question. No, it is not the set you described. The set you're describing is the *sum* of $Sp(K)$ and $Sp(L)$. By definition, if $U, W$ are subspaces of $V$, then
$$U + W = \{u + w : u \in U, w \in W\}$$

Comment: Thank you! Made it very clear :)